# measure dev/urandom efficiency

Tags: linux, bash, random

I have to measure efficiency of /dev/urandom as an assignment. I've got the following task: Check, how many bytes of data you can get from /dev/urandom in 1 minute. Don't write taken data on disk, as it could slow everything down.

I've tried

```
timeout 60s cat /dev/urandom | wc -c
```

But all I receive was just "Terminated" message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `--foreground` option:

```
timeout --foreground 60s cat /dev/urandom | wc -c
```

> `--foreground`: when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt, allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out

Answer (score 1):

Group your commands:

```
$ { timeout 60s cat /dev/urandom; } | wc -c
```

But 60 seconds seems to be on the high side to me:

```
$ { timeout 1s cat /dev/urandom; } | wc -c
6160384                                     ### that's 6 Million bytes.

$ { timeout 10s cat /dev/urandom; } | wc -c
63143936                                    ### that's 63 Million bytes.


$ { timeout 10s cat /dev/urandom; } | wc -c
354844672                                   ### that's ~355 Million bytes.
```

But the last measure is affected by anything the computer did in that period of time.